# JavaScript comment not closed, but highlighted, trashes the whole code

Tags: javascript, comments, syntax-highlighting

I am using the latest NotePad for JS, I was debugging my code and commented out a section, but didn't close the comment tag. The comment was still highlighted in green as if it actually was commeneted out, so I just left it this way. But my code wouldn't run until I closed the tag. The only issue was the **highlighting** as it served as a hint that my code was commented out. Am i missing out on something? 
Thank you for help.

```
function submitDrinkAnswer() {
    alert(userDrinkAnswer);
}

/*findMatch(function() {
    for (let myAnswersIndex = 0; myAnswersIndex < myAnswers.length; myAnswersIndex++) {
        for (let hisAnswersIndex = 0; hisAnswersIndex < hisAnswers.length; hisAnswersIndex++) {
          if (myAnswers[myAnswersIndex] === hisAnswers[hisAnswersIndex]) {
         console.log(myAnswers[myAnswersIndex]);
          }
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re confused about. An unclosed comment is a syntactical error. Are you asking _why_ unclosed comments are still highlighted as comments in NotePad?

Comment: exactly, it got me confused

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to comment out JavaScript code.

One is: `//`

and the other: `/* */`

It would help if you actually posted your code so we could see where the error lies. For now, make sure that all comments are closed with the appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see what the problem is. NotePad for JS has its particular quirks. One of them is that it will highlight a commented section whether or not you have closed it.

Since you can't run code without closing the comments, it stays highlighted. And once you *close* the comment, then it remains highlighted to indicate that you have a section which is commented out.

If you don't like this highlighting behavior I suggest getting another text editor, or deleting the highlighting functionality under the style configurator.

Comment: Thank you! It got me for the whole day, I knew smth was plain wrong with the NotePad.